# Adding doctype url causes eternal refreshing

Tags: html, doctype

I have a page that had the doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

I need to add the URL to the end, or jQuery's datepicker does not display correctly.  When I make the doctype say:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

The page begins to refresh it self over and over.  I can't put up the code here because of NDA, but I am hoping that someone may know what would cause this to happen.

UPDATE: It looks like this doctype has problems with EasyListBox, which seems to be my problem.

Comment: PS I understand that the Doctype is not the problem, setting it made the problem (in the code somewhere) manifest it self.  

I was hoping that some doctype guru out there may know what setting the URL may change (as far as the way the page is interpreted) that would cause this loop, that it wouldn't cause if the URL is left out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Doctype declaration shouldn't be causing the infinite refresh. It is most likely a bug in your code.

Comment: I understand that the doctype isn't the problem, it just made the problem show it self.  This is a massive page that includes a lot of different scripts, most of which I did not write, so finding that problem is not going to be easy.  I was just hoping there was a common mistake that setting the doctype reveals that would cause the refresh

Comment: Try setting up an event handler when the page refreshes (onbeforeunload). Then, you could possibly use a javascript debugger to find what caused the page to refresh.

Comment: Now there is a good idea!  I will try that out and let you know.

Comment: The onbeforeload did help debug, good call on that one.  It seems that my problem may be tied to EasyListBox.  I am going to remove it and see if that fixes my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The doctype has nothing to do with that so it must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pare down the page so that it still replicates the error, but no longer exposes anything that might be under NDA. If you still haven't found the bug by this process of elimination, then you'll be able to post the page for us to see :)

Answer (score 0):

Just try the simplest doctype ever,

```
<!doctype html>
```

the html5 doctype. It should work fine with the JQ date picker and pretty much everything else.

Comment: Worth a try, I will post results

Comment: This doctype still causes the refresh, even without the URL added.

Comment: It really must be something else. Sounds like you're on to it.

Answer (score 0):

Doc-type and Jquery datepicker don't have a direct relationship, your problem for the refreshing loop on your page is without any doubt on your code...

Post your code or provide some link to it to allow us to help you correctly!

Ps: Doc-type does influence the way your browser reads and interpreters your page...